# How to add Connection Outlets from separate class file (.m) Objects to ViewController's MainStoryboard

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2

I want to maintain data encapsulation and have separated an `NSObject` class (.h and .m file) from my `ViewController.m`.

I have the Objective-C working correctly where my class is instantiated in the `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` and I can set, get and `NSLog` the private values via my `NSObject`'s methods.

What I can't do is in the `MainStoryboard` assign the Connection Outlets and Received Actions.  My `IBOutlets` (a `UILabel` and `UIButton`) aren't showing in the Connection Inspector.  However, I have many Objects in my `ViewController`'s .[hm] file that I can setup the Outlet Connections to.  It's just this new file's Objects that I can't view in the storyboard tool.

What am I doing wrong?

```
//  GameTimer.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface GameTimer : NSObject {
    UILabel *gameTimerLabel;
    NSTimer *gameTimer;
    unsigned int gameTimerTicks;  
}
@property unsigned int gameTimerTicks;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *gameTimerLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *startButton;
// instantiate the timer
- (IBAction)onStartPressed:(id)sender;
// Update the gameTimerLabel, show new value to user
- (void)gameTimerShow;
// selector func for our timer, manages the tick count for all our timers
- (void)gameTimerEvent;
@end

//  FirstViewController.m
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "GameTimer.h"
@interface FirstViewController ()
@end
@implementation FirstViewController
GameTimer *myGameClock;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myGameClock = [[GameTimer alloc] init];
    [myGameClock setGameTimerTicks:33*10];  
    [myGameClock gameTimerShow];
    unsigned long myticks = myGameClock.gameTimerTicks;
    NSLog(@"Ticks=%lu", myticks);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be confusing encapsulation the role of a controller.  Since the Cocoa Touch framework is a Model-View-Controller, the Controller is the "manager" that sits between the View's user interpretation and the Model's data and business rules.  Therefore you must put your IBOutlets and IBActions in your UIViewController subclasses.

Build your timer into a separate class.  The timer would then be considered part of the model that other controllers or other objects of the model can instantiate as needed.  Let your Controller instantiate a "Timer".  Then use the Controller to manage the "Timer" operations.  If you need to display the elapsed time, then the Controller should get the elapsed time from the "Timer" object and put it in the appropriate control.  If you need to set the length of time in the "Timer" then the Controller will get the value from a View's control and put it in the "Timer".

Hope this helps